# Programmatically remove group from Microsoft Word ribbon

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I've created a Microsoft Word Office 2010 VSTO add-in and am looking for a way to programmatically remove a specific group from the ribbon when the add-in launches. At a later stage users should be able to re-add this group using Customize Ribbon functionality in Word:

[image]

There is functionality to toggle the **visibility** of a group but if I do this attempts to make the group visible again using Customize Ribbon fail:

```
groupName.Visible = false;
```

I've searched quite a bit on this topic but can't find anything helpful with regards to removing ribbon groups, any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that adding and removing groups in VSTO add-ins is reserved for inner workings of Microsoft Word. More info on this topic can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/63e5a99d-ff24-48a9-b56c-a9e962654b58)

The only solution close to what I'm lookin for is to have a control on the ribbon(toggle button or checkbox) which set's the visibility of the group